# Vue changes not detected on Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi guys Im working with Vue, and Im trying to make recursive Tree from Flat list, I would like to toogle expanded property of each item when someone clicks on it, but for some reason it is not changin

It is happening in this function

```
  expandNode(item) {
      console.log("HERERERER");
      item.expand = false;
      this.$set(item, "expand", false);
    }
```

I would like my Array to be reactive but for some reason it is not, Is it maybe the way Im reapacking the data or something else, Could someone take a look ??

Here is my CodeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-tree-51rbs

this is the component code

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <tr v-for="(item ,index)  in flatArray" :key="index">
      <div class="item" @click="expandNode(item)">
        <div class="element" v-show="item.expand">
          {{ item.expand }}
          <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
    data: { default: () => null, type: Array }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      flatArray: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let arr = [];
    console.log("HERERER");
    this.recursive(this.data, arr, 0, null, -1);
    this.flatArray = arr;
    console.log(this.flatArray);
  },
  computed: {
    setPadding(item) {
      return `padding-left: ${item.level * 30}px;`;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    recursive(obj, newObj, level, parent, parentIndex) {
      obj.forEach(node => {
        if (node.children && node.children.length != 0) {
          node.level = level;
          node.leaf = false;
          node.expand = true;
          node.parent = parent;
          node.parentIndex = parent ? parentIndex : null;
          newObj.push(node);
          this.recursive(
            node.children,
            newObj,
            node.level + 1,
            node,
            newObj.indexOf(node)
          );
        } else {
          node.level = level;
          node.leaf = true;
          node.expand = true;
          node.parent = obj;
          node.parentIndex = parent ? parentIndex : null;
          newObj.push(node);
          return false;
        }
      });
    },
    expandNode(item) {
      console.log("HERERERER");
      item.expand = false;
      this.$set(item, "expand", false);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: When you add nodes to your array, try pushing clones (`const newNode = { ...node}`) instead of just references to already existing objects.

Comment: Note that `set` does work on array items https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/tj5n174c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you're not seeing an update is that the array has no reason to recalculate. You're updating `this.$set(item, "expand", false);` an object that is not reactive. The reason it's not reactive is because you're not using `$set` method when you're creating the object.

here is what it would look like if you use `$set` correctly during object creation.

```js
    recursive(obj, newObj, level, parent, parentIndex) {
      obj.forEach(node => {
        this.$set(node, "level", level);
        this.$set(node, "expand", true);
        this.$set(node, "parentIndex", parent ? parentIndex : null);
        if (node.children && node.children.length !== 0) {
          this.$set(node, "leaf", false);
          this.$set(node, "parent", parent);
          newObj.push(node);
          this.recursive(
            node.children,
            newObj,
            node.level + 1,
            node,
            newObj.indexOf(node)
          );
        } else {
          this.$set(node, "leaf", true);
          this.$set(node, "parent", obj);
          newObj.push(node);
          return false;
        }
      });
    },
```

note that you can now use `item.expand = false`

```js
    expandNode(item) {
      item.expand = false;
      // this.$set(item, "expand", false);  <== not needed
    }
```

you can see in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-platform-fqufg)

---

#### Alternatively,...

Here is code that might work for you that doesn't rely on reactivity

Note that:

- I'm re-calculating and re-assigning the array with `this.flatArray = flattenTree(this.data);`
- The idea is that the nested objects are a "source of truth", and the flattened array is there to allow the template to render.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <tr v-for="(item ,index) in flatArray" :key="index">
      <div
        @click="toggleExpandNode(item)"
        class="item"
        :style="{'margin-left':item.level * 1.6 +'em'}"
      >
        <div class="element">
          <span v-if="item.leaf">&#9900;</span>
          <span v-else-if="item.expand">&#9662;</span>
          <span v-else>&#9656;</span>
          &nbsp;
          <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const flattenTree = obj => {
  const flatTreeArr = [];
  let depth = 0;

  const flatten = (node, parentNode) => {
    flatTreeArr.push(node);
    node.level = depth;
    node.leaf = true;
    node.parent = parentNode;
    node.expand = node.expand === undefined ? true : node.expand;
    if (node.children) {
      node.leaf = false;
      if (node.expand) {
        depth++;
        node.children.forEach(br => flatten(br, node));
        depth--;
      }
    }
  };

  obj.forEach(br => flatten(br, null));
  return flatTreeArr;
};

export default {
  props: {
    data: { default: () => null, type: Array }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      flatArray: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.flatArray = flattenTree(this.data);
  },
  methods: {
    toggleExpandNode(item) {
      item.expand = !item.expand;
      this.flatArray = flattenTree(this.data);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

see it in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-wind-yjjr0)

Comment: Thank you so much, will check it now :)

Comment: updated answer with `$set` method, which is more "correct" for vue and better addresses the question.

Comment: in this case wouldnt it be faster to use recursion ?

Comment: Is it really needed to always loop trough entire array ?

Answer (score 1):

If `item` object has no initial `expand` property, you **must** declare it as observable using `this.$set(item, ...)`.

Directly adding new property like `item.expand = ...` skips this step and `this.$set` ignores it. Such property will not be reactive.

More about this in here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: What's interesting is the items *do* have `expand` at the time `flatArray` is created from `arr`.  If you create `arr` without using the nodes from the prop, everything works.  So it's actually not enough that they have an initial `expand` property in `flatArray`, they also can't use previously reactive data and add properties without `set`.

Comment: @Darius what do you mean they cant use previusly reactive data ?